# Xcode 4 missing "use core data" checkbox for all project templates

Tags: core-data, xcode4

I have just installed Xcode 4 and I am trying to create projects that use core data.  However, the checkbox to use core data is not available in any of the project templates.  Has anyone else run into this or know how to solve it.  I have tried reinstalling Xcode, which does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 17):

The "Use Core Data" checkbox appears only when you choose certain kinds of templates, like the Empty Application iOS template...

[image]

[image]

Try the different templates to see exactly for which one Core Data is available...

Comment: I have no idea. There is no technical reason why Core Data shouldn't work for all templates.

Comment: Lindemann see my answer to know why Apple thinks its not suitable to include CoreData option in all the project templates

Comment: Unbelievable. For a company who goes to the lengths of writing "Human Interface Guidelines" to ensure your apps are user-friendly, Apple doesn't half make life difficult for us developers.  It's bizarre that "Use Core Data" isn't given as an OPTION in all project types (even if they chose to disable it on the "simpler" option types).

Answer (score 4):

As the most upvoted answer of Lindemann says, CoreData is not available for all the project templates. If you wonder why is that, then here is Apple's reason for that.

> **Important:** Not all templates offer a Core Data option.
>       Core Data is an advanced technology that is not required for creating simple applications.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a new project using one of the main templates like "Cocoa Application"? If you're used to one of the preview releases of Xcode 4, note the options are no longer on the main template sheet but rather show up on a second sheet after choosing a template.

Comment: It's the second sheet that got me, and unfortunately core data isn't built into all of the iOS project templates. Have to manually add it now for a "window based" application.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I create a new empty application test project with Core Data included and just copy and paste the CD stuff into my app.  For example, I recently created a tab based app and did that: created a test empty application with core data and just copied the CD model as well as the CD contents of the App Delegate .m and .h to my app's App Delegate .m .h files.

Answer (score 0):

You can change manually template to add coredata checkbox.

- Right-click on xCode app icon, and show content package.
- Then follow this :
  http://rypearts.com/proof/bob/r1/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/
  and this : http://ennio.sperimentando.it/2011/08/22/xcode-setting-the-tab-bar-project-template-to-support-core-data-4/

Comment: Sadly, both of these links are broken.

Answer (score -1):

I am a totally new to mac. But I found something here. Is it help or not?

*Choose Options for your new project* -> *Storage: Core Data*:

[image: Choose Options for your Project > Storage: Core Data]