# Creation of Core Data in iOS

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4.5

Hi Iam new to this Objective C, I need to know how to work with the core data, can any one help me  ..

Comment: Sure, you can find excellent tutorials [here](http://google.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the link: [Xcode 4 missing "use core data" checkbox for all project templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083828/xcode-4-missing-use-core-data-checkbox-for-all-project-templates) for add the core data in your project and how to use the core data for see the link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjdxjgdbf-k

Comment: Thanks for your suggession

Answer (score 0):

for my experience best way to learn core data in Book " head first iphone and ipad development "