# Where is the Enable Core Data Button in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm sorry, this is simply driving me crazy. I was trying to follow the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432058/no-managedobjectcontext-defined-in-my-appdelegate/19432410#19432410) StackOverflow question, but I simply can't find the **Use Core Data** button anywhere in Xcode 5 or 6.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you creating a new project or trying to add Core Data to your project?

Comment: Trying to add to an existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a new project, with appropriate template, the checkbox will be presented in the process of creating the project.

You can use Core Data in any existing project. If you didn't select that option at the time of creation, you will need to add the library manually and then create an .xcdatamodeld file as well. That is basically what the template does.

If you haven't progressed in development, you may want to go back and start from scratch as the template provides some boiler plate code that you will now need to create manually.

You can see some relevant discussion and info that may be helpful in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083828/xcode-4-missing-use-core-data-checkbox-for-all-project-templates).

Comment: Thanks! I just created a new project and copy/pasted my code over. Compiled correctly and without errors. Thanks!